# using DictVectorizer to convert strings

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dictvectorizer

```
satisfaction_level  last_evaluation number_project  average_montly_hours    time_spend_company  Work_accident   left    promotion_last_5years   dept    salary
0.38    0.53    2   157 3   0   1   0   TECHNICAL   low
0.8 0.86    5   262 6   0   1   0   HR  medium
0.11    0.88    7   272 4   0   1   0   HR  medium
0.72    0.87    5   223 5   0   1   0   FINANCE low
0.37    0.52    2   159 3   0   1   0   MARKETING   low
0.41    0.5 2   153 3   0   1   0   TECHNICAL   low
0.1 0.77    6   247 4   0   1   0   HR  low
0.92    0.85    5   259 5   0   1   0   FINANCE low
0.89    1   5   224 5   0   1   0   HR  low
```

I used the above data and tried to convert C using DictVectorizer. Code is given below

---

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

dv=DictVectorizer() 
hr_data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\data\HR_comma_sep.csv")
dv.fit_transform(X=hr_data.dept)
```

But it threw error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 4):

Use [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
In [304]: df.dept
Out[304]:
0    TECHNICAL
1           HR
2           HR
3      FINANCE
4    MARKETING
5    TECHNICAL
6           HR
7      FINANCE
8           HR
Name: dept, dtype: object

In [305]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

In [306]: le = LabelEncoder()

In [307]: df['dept'] = le.fit_transform(df['dept'])

In [308]: df.dept
Out[308]:
0    3
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    2
5    3
6    1
7    0
8    1
Name: dept, dtype: int64

In [309]: le.classes_
Out[309]: array(['FINANCE', 'HR', 'MARKETING', 'TECHNICAL'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or we may using `category`

```
df.dept.astype('category').cat.codes
Out[925]: 
0    3
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    2
5    3
6    1
7    0
8    1
dtype: int8

df.dept.astype('category').cat.categories
Out[926]: Index(['FINANCE', 'HR', 'MARKETING', 'TECHNICAL'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I had the same problem and solved it:
First, change the data frame to the dictionary

```
data_dict = data.to_dict()

dv = DictVectorizer(sparse = False, dtype = int)
dv.fit_transform(data['column'])
```

Worked for me!

Comment: Did you mean to put `dv.fit_transform(data_dict['column'])` ? You create the dictionary but never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should try this as well:

If the values are strings, then transform them into numerical categories first using LabelEncoder, then use DictVectorizer:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
data_le = le.fit_transform(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because `DictVectorizer` is a class intended for dictionaries while you are applying to a Series object (the result of accessing a column by dictionary or attribute style). For this case I would suggest the class [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) from `sklearn.preprocessing`.

`DictVectorizer` works for dictionaries:

```py
vec = DictVectorizer(sparse = False, dtype = int)
data = [{'character': 'Porthos'},{'character': 'Athos'},
        {'character': 'Aramis'}, {'character': 'Athos'},
        {'character': 'Aramis'}

vec.fit_transform(data)
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

But not so much for Series or DataFrames:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
vec.fit_transform(data)

*long error*
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

For Pandas' DataFrames and Series use `OneHotEncoder`:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
vec = OneHotEncoder(sparse = False, dtype = int)
vec.fit_transform(data)
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```